# Sentry: where can I see React profiles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry

I have, to the best of my knowledge, followed the applicable Sentry documentation to setup React profiling in my webapp:

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/features/component-tracking/?original_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

However, where in the Sentry GUI can I see these profiles? They do not seem to be under Performance which would be the natural place.

I do not have Browser profiling enabled, but nothing in the documentation indicates that this should be needed for React Profiling to work:

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/profiling/?original_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Answer (score 0):

`Sentry.withProfiler()` predates Sentry's profiling functionality and emits spans which are part of the "performance" functionality.

`withProfiler()` needs a transaction to be active and on the scope.

If you add the `BrowserTracing` integration to your `Sentry.init()` call, the SDK will automatically start transactions and put them on the scopes for initial page loads and navigations.

Comment: I do have BrowserTracing enabled and properly setup, and Sentry is correctly recording transactions. Will see if I can see them under the available spans.